# How to get list of files in partition?

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, diskpart

[image]

I'm pretty sure partition 5 (33.86GB) and 6 (3.94GB) is dualbooted Ubuntu with the swap space.

Now I don't know what partition 7 (22.75GB) contains, or whether or not it is safe to delete.

I right-clicked it but can't assign a drive number, its greyed out. Is there some way for me to know what exists on that partition? If its empty then I would delete it.

Answer (score 0):

It might be EXT4 (or any other Linux based partition format) which you can't natively browse in Windows. I suggest you boot into a Live Linux USB (such as live Ubuntu or Linux Mint, you can make a bootable USB using the relevant ISO and Rufus on Windows) if you dont have a Linux install handy and try and mount/browse it in Linux. Otherwise you can still try and mount it usign Ext2fsd for windows but in my opinion it is more hassle than its worth and booting Linux is easier.

After you've mounted it in Linux you can list files in Terminal by running:

```
cd /mnt/partition/ #change directory, assuming /mnt/partition is where you've mounted the partition

ls #gives you files at the root of the partition

find -type f . #this lists all files on the mounted partition. Honestly this won't be very useful and "ls" would help you as it would give you whats in the directory itself.
```

If you run `ls` and see folders like /etc, /usr, /opt then its likely another Linux install. It might also be a mounted folder like /home or /usr for a Linux install. Whatever it is, you'd be able to see if you mount it in Linux.

Answer (score 0):

Use Testdisk and create a log file to get all the necessary info. Testdisk recognizes a lot an runs on Windows, Linux and Mac.